If $u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, then $\nabla u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$?

(And as well, a transcription for those unable to load images:)

Remark 2. There is a local form of Corollary 1, namely if $u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, then for every $k>0$, $\mathrm e^{k|u|}\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$. [ Here we use the well-known fact that $u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$ imply $\nabla u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$. ]

As shown in the figure, I tried to prove this "well-known fact" by integral by parts. However, I only know that
$$
\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla\phi<\infty
$$
for every $\phi\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$, which is not enough to deduce that $\nabla u\in L^1_{\text{loc}}$. The exponent is $1$, so I think it is not enough to deduce that $u\in W^{2,1}_{\text{loc}}$. Any help will be appreciated a lot!

Use interpolation, i.e. Gagliardo-Nirenberg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo–Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality

@fwd Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the G-N inequality applies only when $u\in L^p(\Omega)$, not $L^p_{\text{loc}}$. Can this be rectified with a mollifier?

@K.defaoite to show that $\nabla u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, we show that $\nabla u \in L^1(V)$ for each $V$ compactly contained in $\Omega$. So we apply G-N for each such $V$.

@fwd How silly of me. Thanks.

@fwd Though, I wonder if there is a way to show it without needing such heavy machinery.

@fwd Thanks for your hint! To apply the G-N interpolation inequality, I think it is necessary to show that $|\Delta u|_1\geq c|\nabla^2 u|_1$ for some constant $c>0$. Is this clear?

@KimuraLeo we can control the derivatives one at a time: $\Vert \partial_j u \Vert_{L^1(V)} \lesssim \Vert \partial^2_{j} u \Vert_{L^1(V)}^{1/2} \Vert u \Vert_{L^1(V)}^{1/2} + \Vert u \Vert_{L^1(V)}$

Also, I’m taking for granted that the boundary of your domain is sufficiently smooth

@fwd In the original paper of Nirenberg, the notation $|\partial_j u|_1$ means the maximum $L^1$ integral among all the first partial derivative. Or do you mean using the G-N inequality in 1-dimensional setting? If we consider $n=1$, then I think the G-N inequality does work! Thanks!

Yes indeed, I meant the 1-D inequalities. This way we avoid having to control mixed partials in $\nabla^2 u$.

@fwd Thanks a lot! I've figured it out!

@KimuraLeo If you could, please show your solution in an answer. (Answering your own questions is allowed and encouraged on MSE.)
